# Magento 2: Adding Categories Sidebar

Tags: php, magento2

I am using Magento 2.1 with a custom theme. The theme has the left sidebar file:

```
/app/design/frontend/.../Magento_Catalog/templates/navigation/left.phtml
```

How do I display this file on my homepage and category pages as a left sidebar? Do I need to create a new block and somehow reference this file?

I don't want to use another module when showing this sidebar should be so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Download this free extension to show categories on homepage in Magento 2 in sidebar.

https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-home-categories